# Error in Form Action attribute struts2

Tags: java, forms, jsp, url, struts2

My login.jsp is in the web folder.

And action for this is specified as :

### struts.xml

```
<package name="admin" extends="struts-default" namespace="/secure">

<action class="actions.LoginAction" name="authenticateUser">
    <result name="success" type="redirect">index</result>
    <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/login.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
```

### login.jsp

```
<s:form action="secure/authenticateUser" method="post">

</s:form>
```

========================

At first request it works.

but if `validate()` method of action returns errors then it creates url as:

"secure/secure/authenticateUser" for the Form action attribute.

I also tried `<s:url>` tag but still same problem can anybody help me.
or may provide alternate solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action attribute on the form tag possibly has a wrong name. Use

```
<s:form namespace="/secure" action="authenticateUser" method="post">
```

Comment: syntactically you are right but it still generates following form tag.    <form id="authenticateUser" name="authenticateUser" action="authenticateUser.action" method="post">

Comment: No, it's not possible if you are using standard struts tags and deployed all necessary libs.